# How to pass values to ? enclosed within single quotes in java

Tags: java

I have a textbox in which user enters the date like 29-NOV-2013.

I want the following string to be converted:

```
String sql = "select * from review where creationdate like '?%' order by creationdate desc";
```

(into)

```
String sql = "select * from review where creationdate like '29-NOV-2013%' order by creationdate desc";
```

using parameter placeholders.
How do I Do that?

Comment: [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = 
     con.prepareStatement("select * from review where creationdate like ? order by creationdate desc");
pstmt.setString(1, "29-NOV-2013%")
```

Comment: Hi Mik378 im primarily a C# guy so i am noob. How should i execute this function using model2

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setString(position,value)` of `PreparedStatement` to set value at placeholder `?`.

```
 String sql = "select * from review where creationdate like '?%' 
               order by creationdate desc";

PreparedStatement pstmt=con.createPreparedStatement(sql);
pstm.setString(1,textbox.getText());
                    //It will get the value from textbox e.g. 29-NOV-2013
```

Comment: Hi Masud im primarily a C# guy so i am noob.
How should i execute this function using model2

Comment: @user3053596, Is your problem have solved? Have a look at this tutorial, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Here Con is the connection string?How to execute it against the database?